# Custom stepper with progress bar material ui, react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, jss

I am working on a stepper and I am using the code from https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-beaver-45ky0?file=/src/CustomStepper.js

Over here the progress between two steps is on click of next button, I want to show it on the basis of form fields filled.

Secondly, I want to save the progress of user in json file, so that when the user log in again, he must resume from where he left. I an unable to know how to do this.
I am new to react.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.